# External JavaScript file doesn’t get executed

Tags: javascript, html

I can’t get my external JavaScript to run.

My `index.html` is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <script> console.log("foo") </script>

  <!-- NOT WORKING-->
  <script src="scripts/notworking.js" type="javascript"></script>

  <script> console.log("bar") </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my `notworking.js` contains only the following two lines:

```js
console.log("working?")
alert("working!");
```

But nothing happens. Only the `"foo"` and `"bar"` from the `index.html` file are displayed.

Comment: Did you get any error on loading `notworking.js` to the index.html

Comment: no, i dont get an error. If i add a file that not exists for example notworkingAAA.js then i get an 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!-- NOT WORKING-->
<script src="scripts/notworking.js" type="javascript"></script>
```

`type="javascript"` is no valid MIME type.

Use `type="text/javascript"` or simply remove it.